# Google Compute Engine Failed to Activate Service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1'

Tags: centos7, dbus

My GCE instance is working perfectly fine until this morning when I can't connect to it via SSH (both via putty and browser based client). I read that it could be due to disk already full. however, df -h showed that I'm just using 71% of the disk. At any rate, I tried to increase the disk size using the GUI and then I restarted the instance. And then it got worse.

I'm getting the error below now.

```
centos7-sg login: Jan 26 07:08:34 centos7-sg systemd: postfix.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 26 07:08:34 centos7-sg systemd: Failed to start Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Jan 26 07:08:34 centos7-sg systemd: Unit postfix.service entered failed state.
Jan 26 07:08:34 centos7-sg systemd: postfix.service failed.
Jan 26 07:08:38 centos7-sg instance-setup: ERROR GET request error retrieving metadata. <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>.
Jan 26 07:08:58 centos7-sg dbus[301]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1': timed out
Jan 26 07:08:58 centos7-sg dbus-daemon: dbus[301]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1': timed out
Jan 26 07:08:58 centos7-sg tuned: 2018-01-26 07:08:58,422 ERROR    dbus.proxies: Introspect error on org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1:/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Activation of org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 timed out
Jan 26 07:08:58 centos7-sg tuned: ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1:/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Activation of org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 timed out
```

one more thing I noticed based on the log is that there's a significant increase in CPU utilization for 7 hours prior to the restart. Usually, the instance hover between 1.5-3% CPU utilization but this morning, it's between 10 and 15%. I don't know if there is any connection, though.

Environment details:

```
CentOS7
NGINX
Postgres
Gunicorn
Python
Django
```

Though I'm more interested in retrieving the postgres database(my local copy is 2weeks old), I'd like to now how to solve this problem.

**EDIT**
Even my creating instance from my 03-jan snapshot result to

```
instance-setup: ERROR GET request error retrieving metadata
```

**EDIT 2**
I checked the whole serial console. The problem started with

```
acpi PNP0A03:00: fail to add MMCONFIG information, can't access extended PCI configuration space under this bridge.
```

end then

```
[_[1;31mFAILED_[0m] Failed to start Configure read-only root support.

[_[1;31mFAILED_[0m] Failed to start Login Service.
```

and so on.
I managed to retrieve the data by following the instructions in [gce-discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/BpEllqbT-gc)

> 1.- Create a snapshot of that VM's disk. 
>   2.- Create a new disk with that snapshot from above. 
>   3.- Instantiate a new VM with the same OS you have in the affected instance. 
>  When doing so, specify in the original configuration screen
>   that you wish the previously mentioned disk drive to be attached as
>   extra drive to your new instance (attach a non-root persistent disk). 
>   If you have problems in step 3. you can also add the disk to an
>   existing instance. 
>   4.- Boot the new instance. 
>   5.- Access the new instance via SSH, mount the secondary hard drive, and access it to retrieve the original system's config and log files.